# Can I use external file to manage JNDI name?

Tags: jakarta-ee, jndi, jboss7.x, ejb-3.1

I use different container to call `EJB3`(EJB on JBOSS AS 7.1 and Struts2 on Tomcat 7.0). So I need using `JNDI` to lookup EJB service.
However, the JNDI name is very very long and very hard-code with class:

```
ejb:[EAR Project name]/[EJB project name]/[Distinct Name]/[Session Bean Name]![Remote Interface Name]
```

So does there any way can use external file to manage/save/define name `@Stateless(name="XXX"))`?

Does any one have idea or suggestion?

Thanks all.